# When Should I define a mapping relationship between two JPA entitites and why

Tags: jpa, relationship

Say I have 2 JPA entites, Order and Item. There is a one to many relationship between them (defined by a FK in the DB). But say that I never actually need to get Item(s) from an Order or and Order from an Item.

All I need to do is get an Order *using* and item id or an Item *using* an Order id.

I can approach this in two ways:

Without explicitly mapping the entities (with the appropriate annotations...) but simply querying as follows:

```
SELECT Order From Order, Item WHERE Order.orderID = Item.orderID and Item.ItemID = :x
```

Or I can map explictly and do:

```
SELECT Order from From Order, Item WHERE Order = Item.Order AND ITEM.ID = :x
```

Is there a technical reason why one is approach is preferable to the other?

Comment: The proper query would be `select o from Item i join i.order o where i.itemId = :itemId)`. IMO, the question is moot: if there is a relation between an order and its items in the database, it exists for a good reason, and you will have a use-case where you need to get one from the other. So, design it properly, with an association, from the start. Even this query shows that you need a join, and joins in JPQL work with associations between entities.

Comment: thank you, will do